# Python 2.x super __init__ inheritance doesn't work when parent doesn't inherit from object

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super, new-style-class

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
class Frame:
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image

class Eye(Frame):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(Eye, self).__init__()
        self.some_other_defined_stuff()
```

I'm trying to extend the `__init__()` method so that when I instantiate an 'Eye' it does a bunch of other stuff (self.some_other_defined_stuff()), in addition to what Frame sets up. `Frame.__init__()` needs to run first.

I get the following error:

```
super(Eye, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Which I do not understand the logical cause of. Can someone explain please? I'm used to just typing 'super' in ruby.

Comment: `Frame` must extend `object`. `super` will only work on new-style classes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two errors here:

1. `super()` only works for [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes); use `object` as a base class for `Frame` to make it use new-style semantics.
2. You still need to call the overridden method with the right arguments; pass in `image` to the `__init__` call.

So the correct code would be:

```
class Frame(object):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image

class Eye(Frame):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(Eye, self).__init__(image)
        self.some_other_defined_stuff()
```

Comment: Would the reference to `object` be redundant in Python > 3.X?

Comment: @gented: yes, `object` as a base class is implied in Python 3 (as there are no old-style classes anymore).

Answer (score 13):

`Frame` must extend `object` because only the new style classes support `super` call you make in `Eye` like so:

```
class Frame(object):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image

class Eye(Frame):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(Eye, self).__init__(image)
        self.some_other_defined_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write :`__metaclass__ = type` at the top of the code then we can Access super class

```
__metaclass__ = type
class Vehicle:
                def start(self):
                                print("Starting engine")
                def stop(self):
                                print("Stopping engine")                            
class TwoWheeler(Vehicle):
                def say(self):
                    super(TwoWheeler,self).start()
                    print("I have two wheels")
                    super(TwoWheeler,self).stop()                            
Pulsar=TwoWheeler()
Pulsar.say()
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi see my working codes for python 2.7

```
__metaclass__ = type
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname + ", " + str(self.age)

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, staffnum):
        super(Employee, self).__init__(first, last, age)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def __str__(self):
        return super(Employee, self).__str__() + ", " +  self.staffnumber


x = Person("Marge", "Simpson", 36)
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", 28, "1007")

print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: To improve this answer, please check your formatting and provide an explanation for your code.